# Compare common files between directories

Tags: bash, shell

Using diff (or a similar command), I want the differences between two directories, except I only want the differences in the files which are common to both the directories. If a file/directory is present in one of the directories and not in the other, it should be completely eliminated from the output. Can I do this with diff itself?

I prefer already-implemented tools over hacks. But please suggest whatever you can.

Comment: Define "hacks". Making few standard tools work together is a part of Unix Philosophy and I wouldn't call it a hack. Would you?

Comment: By hacks, I mean methods with potential side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for file1 in "$directory1"/*
do
    file2="$directory2/$(basename "$file1")"
    [[ -f "$file2") ]] && diff "$file1" "$file2"
done
```

Comment: What if `file1` is not a regular file? What if it's a directory? What if it contains a file named as the directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost what `diff` does when comparing directories. Your extra requirement means you don't want to see this:

> In the `POSIX` locale, each file that is present in only one directory shall be reported using the following format:
>
> ```
> "Only in %s: %s\n", <directory pathname>, <filename>
> ```

And *maybe* you don't want to see this:

> In the `POSIX` locale, subdirectories that are common to the two directories may be reported with the following format:
>
> ```
> "Common subdirectories: %s and %s\n", <directory1 pathname>, <directory2 pathname>
> ```

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html))</sup>

So filter them out:

```
LC_ALL=POSIX diff directory1 directory2 | grep -v '^Only in' | grep -v '^Common subdirectories'
```

It seems other formats that `diff` uses cannot collide with these two, so there is no risk you remove anything you want to keep.

Notes:

- You may omit `LC_ALL=POSIX` and adjust `grep` patterns to your locale. Localized formats shouldn't collide with other formats but check this possibility just in case.
- Decide if you want `diff -r` or not.